# c# FlowDocument Replace Text with Image, without break after

Tags: c#, replace, rtf

I have a generated RTF `FlowDocument`s with "[x]" and "[   ]" and need to replace them with checkboxes.

Currently I use Images, looping and do it like this:

```
//rtf_vorschau is a Flowdocumentreader
while (SelectPlaceholderRTF("[X]", rtf_vorschau))
{
    using (MemoryStream tmpStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        //WPF                            
        RichTextBox tmprtf = new RichTextBox();
        Image tmpimg = new Image();
        Paragraph tmppara = new Paragraph();
        tmpimg.Source = new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("Sonstiges\\checkbox_checked.PNG") as ImageSource;
        
        tmppara.Inlines.Add(tmpimg);                              
        tmprtf.Document.Blocks.Add(tmppara) ;                            
    
        TextRange tmprange = new TextRange(tmprtf.Document.ContentStart, tmprtf.Document.ContentEnd);
        tmprange.Save(tmpStream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
   
        rtf_vorschau.Selection.Load(tmpStream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
    } 
}
```

This works, but my Problem is the Linebreak behind.
[image]

So "[X] bla bla" is changing to "(the checkbox image)(linebreak) bla bla" is there a simple way to avoid the linebreak after my Paragraph or "include" the image in the selected Run/Paragraph? or using a Forms RichTextBox or manipulate the final rtf file or add a checkbox directly? Finally it will be converted to a (readable) PDF, so replacing it inside the PDF can be another solution.